# Cant seem to figure out post and comment relationship in a basic ROR blog app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So when i try to visit `http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/1/posts/17` I get an error

```
undefined method `post_comments_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fece23212a8>:0x007fece2a7c110>

Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <%= form_for([@post, @comment]) do |f| %>
2: 
3:  <%= f.label :name %>
4:
```

This is referenced to my file  - `/app/views/posts/_form_comment.html.erb where line #1 raised:`

My `/app/views/posts/_form_comment.html.erb` file is as follows -

```
<%= form_for([@post, @comment]) do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :name %>
    <br />
    <%= f.text_field :name%>
    <br />
    <%= f.label :comment %>
    <br />
    <%= f.text_area :comment%>
    <br />

<%= f.submit "Create comment" %>

<% end %>
```

And here is the show method from my PostController

```
def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @comment = @post.comments.build
    @cl = Comment.where(:post_id => @comment[:post_id])

  end
```

Now please note, if empty the contents of the file `/app/views/posts/_form_comment.html.erb` , the pages loads up just fine. Showing the post title and content. Except for the comments section. So, I am guessing something is wrong with the comments section. But i dont know what.

**IMPORTANT NOTE: This didnt happened before. It was working fine until i associated user model with the post model.**
Thanks much.

UPDATE : My routes look like -

```
  resources :users, only: [:show] do 
    resources :posts do
    end
    resources :comments, only: [:create]
  end
```

Comment: do you have a nested resource for the post and the comment controller?

Comment: Yes already have that . I updated my question. Please take a look :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should have something like

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
```

in your routes.  This is what's needed for `url_for` to successfully create the route for `[@post, @comment]`

UPDATE: including nested resource for posts and users

The following is perfectly fine

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end

resources :users do
  resources :posts
end
```

Comment: Yes already have that . I updated my question. Please take a look :)

Comment: aah i see. makes sense. but how do I nest post and user then ?

Comment: I ran rake routes and this is what i got `user_comments POST   /users/:user_id/comments(.:format)       comments#create` So I think thats where the problem is.

Comment: you can have a separate nested resource for users and posts like in my updated answer